# Is the far side of the tidally locked Europa moon safe from Jupiter's radiation?

Tags: radiation, jupiter, europa

From Wikipedia's [Europa (moon); Orbit and rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europa_(moon)#Orbit_and_rotation):

> Europa orbits Jupiter in just over three and a half days, with an orbital radius of about 670,900 km....and is tidally locked to Jupiter, with one hemisphere of Europa constantly facing Jupiter.

[image: tidalmoon] [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Tidal_locking_of_the_Moon_with_the_Earth.gif)

**Question:** Since at least the ice crust of Europa is locked to Jupiter, wouldn't the far side be way less irradiated and always facing away from Jupiter?

Comment: You can find some supplementary information about Jupiter's radiation belts and shielding spacecraft in the following questions and their answers: [If Juno's long orbit means a lower rate of radiation damage, why the planned short orbit?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20251/12102) and [If Juno will experience lower levels of radiation than Galileo did why it will fail so much faster?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18693/12102) and [Why would Juno's originally planned orbit lowering partially mitigate radiation damage?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18686/12102)

Comment: Actually the equatorial parts of Europa have the highest radiation levels. See Mark Foskey ansver about Jupiter's radiation belts for details. You can google "europa lander SDT study pdf" for proof (Chapter 6 there).

Comment: Here's an [image claiming that parts of Europa are worse than others](https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/europa20180723bb-16.jpg) from [this article](https://www.nasa.gov/feature/jpl/radiation-maps-of-jupiter-s-moon-europa-key-to-future-missions). Seems that near 30S-30N from 0-180E are the lat/longitudes that recieve the highest dosage of radiation, as to why I have no idea. Seems odd that it's the East not the West, which could be indicative of something to do with tidal locking.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn The image on the article is somewhat misleading, since it is hiding half the radiation data (the pink area in the leading hemisphere is only shown by dragging the slider to the far left). But it does appear the latitudinal extent is larger in the trailing hemisphere. So we just need to land outside the -30-30 band and we should be good?

Comment: @costcom not quite. on the equator of Europa, lethal radiation dose takes about 50 minutes. On the poles, lethal radiation dose takes about 4 hours. Either place is more dangerous than the Elephant's foot room in Chernobyl.

Answer (score 10):

The radiation that causes problems near Jupiter is not emitted by Jupiter. Jupiter has radiation belts, like Earth's [Van Allen belts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Allen_radiation_belt), but much more intense. This radiation doesn't consist of photons, but high-velocity ions - electrons, protons, and maybe some larger nuclei. They are captured mostly from the solar wind and accelerated by their interaction with the magnetic field of Jupiter.

When I think of radiation I tend to think of something that moves in a straight line, but high-velocity ions are considered to be radiation too, and they curve when they're in a magnetic field. That's why you can have belts of radiation around a planet. So there is no perfect shadow like you would have if the problem consisted of gamma rays (which are photons and do move in straight lines) emitted from Jupiter.

I have not been able to find good information about the closest you could approach Jupiter in an unshielded spacecraft for (say) hours without getting an unacceptable dose. But that would be a different question.

Comment: You can get some hints of the radiation gradient from the europa clipper orbit imgage of wikipedia, http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/97/Europa_Clipper_orbit_away_from_Jupiter_radiation.jpg

Comment: Actually, the main contributor to Jupiter's radiation belts is sulfur dioxide from Io: https://astronomy.com/magazine/ask-astro/2020/02/what-is-the-source-of-jupiters-radiation