# Why is it that harmful for astronauts and technology to get too far into Jupiter's magnetosphere? Shouldn't it rather be protective?

Tags: interplanetary, jupiter, magnetic-field, magnetosphere

Jupiter's radiation belts make it impossible for astronauts to stay on Io, Europa and Ganymede over extended periods of time, as well as getting too close to Jupiter at all. I wonder how close would you have to be to Jupiter for its magnetosphere to finally protect you instead of harming you?

Comment: Given that there are continuous auroras in the polar regions which include X-rays I suspect the answer is 'well inside the atmosphere if you're near the poles'.  I don't know if there is a safe region outside the atmosphere closer to the equator.

Comment: The JUNO trajectory dives below the hard radiation belts near the equator. So you might want to check that.

Comment: Juno goes down to 4,200 km (2,600 mi) altitude near the poles.

Comment: The first two have some information on Juno's orbits relative to Jupiter's radiation bands: [If Juno's long orbit means a lower rate of radiation damage, why the planned short orbit?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20251/12102) and [Why would Juno's originally planned orbit lowering partially mitigate radiation damage?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18686/12102) and [If Juno will experience lower levels of radiation than Galileo did why it will fail so much faster?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18693/12102)